# How do I retrieve a status from twitter with the oauth gem directly?

Tags: ruby, twitter, oauth

How can I grab the json for a tweet using [OAuth](https://github.com/pelle/oauth) gem?

I tried the following but it keeps getting an access denied even though I know my keys are good:

```
def prepare_access_token(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
   consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(consumer_key, consumer_secret, {:site => "https://api.twitter.com"})
   consumer.get_request_token.get_access_token
end

token = prepare_access_token(twitter_consumer_key, twitter_consumer_secret)
token.request(:get, "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show/344726259449860096.json")
```

I know about the twitter gem, but don't want to take on the dependency for something seemingly so simple.

I particular, the following is exceptioning out with a status 401.

`consumer.get_request_token.get_access_token`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't you have a login step in your process? I think you need an `oauth_verifier` to get an access token.

Comment: possibly, oauth is voodoo to me, this sample also failed for me https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/single-user-with-examples

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure what is your application flow but I have a login via twitter app and here is what I have done. ※ This process gives me the user's access_token so I can access its data

First, I have a twitter `app` object that asks for a `request_token`.

```
# defines app's consumer
consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(consumer_key, 
                               consumer_secret,
                               :site => 'https://api.twitter.com',
                               :authorize_path => '/oauth/authenticate',
                               :sign_in => true)
# get the request_token and pass my callback url
request_token = consumer.get_request_token({:oauth_callback => callback_url})
```

You need to store the request_token somehow ! the request_token will get you the access_token but .get_request_token() will generate a different request each time so you need to keep the original to finally obtain your access_token

```
# setting the src of the login button
link_to 'log via twitter', request_token.authorize_url
```

The user logs in.
From Twitter, you get two params in the url `oauth_token` and `oauth_verifier`. You get back the request_token you previously created before the user logs in and since you'll get a different request_token on each access, you need to find the request_token that matches the callback response

```
request_token = request_tokens.detect do |rt|
                  rt.token == oauth_token
                end
# let's get the access_token
access_token = request_token.get_access_token(:oauth_verifier => oauth_verifier)
```

It seems that the access_token are linked with the application you used so you will have to store the `consumer_key`, `consumer_secret`, `access_token.token` and `access_token.secret`

Example on how to get followers count

```
json_http_response = access_token.get("http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?user_id=#{twitter_account_id}"))
followers_count = JSON.parse(json_http_response.body)['followers_count']
```

Later on, if you want to get an access_token back you will be able to do so as

```
access_token =
  OAuth::AccessToken.from_hash(application_consumer,   # the same as the very top
                               {:oauth_token => token, # access_token.token from above
                                :oauth_token_secret => secret}))  # access_token.secret from above
```

Comment: yes I figured out a lot of this mess yesterday, I really want to avoid needing those auth_tokens I would much prefer https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth cause that way our admins only need to add the client token.

Comment: well I kind of got stuck and need to drop to ethereal to see whats going on in the network

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a chance to test this, but [the docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/show/%3Aid) have a completely different URL for show:

**GET** `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json?id={id}`

I'd try that.

Comment: I am kind of stuck before that ... I can't even get the access token from the request token :(

Comment: Sorry mate, I've sworn off the Twitter API.